# Modify sceneView.pointOfView after a certain amount of time

Tags: swift, scenekit

When modifying the sceneView.pointOfView property through code after a certain amount of time, the updated pointOfView value does not immediately affect the 3D model until a tap or interaction with the model occurs. Why does this behavior occur? And how can we fix this?

My code to update pointOfView:

```
import SceneKit

func setupScene() {
    
    guard let scene = SCNScene(named: mockup.fileName) else  {
        print("Unable to load scene file.")
        return
    }
    
    sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
    sceneView.backgroundColor = .clear
    sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
    sceneView.isJitteringEnabled = true
    sceneView.isPlaying = false
    sceneView.scene = scene
    
    
    // If we update the point of view directly, there is no problem.
    //updatePointOfViewAfter(seconds: 0)
    
    // Updating after a few seconds will not take effect unless the user taps or interacts with the 3D model.
    updatePointOfViewAfter(seconds: 3)
    
}


func updatePointOfViewAfter(seconds: Double) {

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) {
        if let newPointOfView = self.sceneView.pointOfView {
            newPointOfView.position = SCNVector3(x: newPointOfView.position.x + 10,
                                                 y: newPointOfView.position.y + 10,
                                                 z: newPointOfView.position.z + 10)
            
            self.sceneView.pointOfView = newPointOfView
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: why do you execute the sequence of rotation, orientation, position and then the transform? each of this properties influences the others, and usually going for the transform should be enough to set everything, like position, rotation, etc... (transform is a Matrix 4x4 Value, that includes everything regarding positioning rotating and orienting a node in a scene). instead of fieldOfView you could also go for the focus property. can you provide more information about how you set and handle this values?

Comment: It is just an example. But any changes made to sceneView.pointOfView or its properties will have no effect when using the default camera.

Comment: could you share a minimal reproducable example project?

Comment: I've updated my question to include a clear example.

Comment: did my answer help you to identify the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am not truly sure, but give this here a try (during the Scene-View configuration)

```
sceneView.rendersContinuously = true
```